# Why Comparable interface can sort object when it is an interface?

Tags: java

Everyone know method in interface is body-empty but how compareTo() can sort an object with return int;

1. How exactly java read compareTo();
2. Is it call some function for sorting? If true, how it call.

```java
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
        int rollno;
        String name;
        int age;

        Student(int rollno, String name, int age) {
            this.rollno = rollno;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int compareTo(Student st) {
            if (age == st.age)
                return 0;
            else if (age < st.age)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comparator doesn't sort; it provides an interface for sort implementations to ask the objects how they should be sorted.

Comment: Have you noticed `public int compareTo(Student st)` in your (?) code?

Comment: Or more precisely, how objects should be *compared* (hence the name).

Comment: `Everyone know method in interface is body-empty` This is not necessarily true, as of Java 8.

Comment: [This](https://stackabuse.com/bubble-sort-in-java/) might be helpful to show how a sorter could call the `compareTo` method for the objects in an array. Getting caught up in the source code for `Arrays.sort` would be distracting.

Comment: @JeffBowman this make sense, but how it call the sort ?

Comment: return an integer is not make sense, it should be an parameter for some function that sort the object

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are providing the implementation of this method which is what you do with an interface. The int compareTo() method signature provided by an interface returns an int which is what is used for the comparison that YOU implement

Edit: This is a snippet from the actual method that the interface provides. You can see that the return type is "int"

[image]

Comment: U said the things that everyone know. What I want is how java read >0, <0 then decide increasing or decreasing

Comment: return an integer is not make sense, it should be an parameter for some function that sort the object

Comment: Check the edit that I made to my answer. You will see that the "int" return type is part of the actual signature. The way that you implement the method will never change from this.